# Advice on good list of American idioms

Tags: idioms, resources

I want to master American idioms and would like to use a complete list as a reference. Would you please suggest one?

Comment: related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7535/is-there-any-online-phrase-dictionary-available and http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/23141/best-source-for-origins-of-expressions-and-idioms/23143#23143

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use  [Idioms.TheFreeDictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/) for reference. Note that the number of idioms in English language is very large. Only the word [head](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/head) lists about 200 idioms.

Comment: "head lists about 200 idioms." And they missed my favorite.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a surprisingly comprehensive list.

[Idiomsite.com](http://www.idiomsite.com/)